# SELECT TOP from each group

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

Sorry guys, I'm gettin crazy with this...

My table:

```
ID Name       Surname     Capital       Capital_Group   Job      Job_Group
----------    --------    -----------   -------------   ------   --------------
1  Michael    Jackson     LessThan50                             Entertainer
1  Michael    Jackson                    Medium                  Entertainer
2  John       Lennon                     Small                   Swimmer
3  Clara      Clinton                    Huge           Runner
3  Clara      Clinton                    Huge                    Sportsmen
```

I just want to get top row from each ID **but not based on anything except that it occurs above the rest** (it's already sorted). Any help apreciated, my sanity is at stake.

Comment: What is it sorted by?

Comment: Ok, so the query needs to specify the sorting criteria? The table is an example, it's sorted based on different criteria. Is there no possibility just to get the highest row?

Comment: For your future reference - the SQL standard doesn't specify that rows are to be stored in a particular order in a table (in fact, implementations are free to store rows however they please).  There are a large number of reasons that this may not be true in any given implementation or moment in time.  If you want rows returned in a particular order, you **MUST** use `ORDER BY`.  For limiting sets pre-ordering other tricks are necessary (like the use of `<` in the current answers).

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that your table sorted by `Capital` in descending order for each `id` and that `id` defines a group, the following may do what you want:

```
select t.*
from mytable as t
where not exists (select 1
                  from mytable as t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.capital > t.capital
                 );
```

Comment: I get 'invalid argument to function with this query:           SELECT t.* FROM qry_DD_Doubling as t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM qry_DD_Doubling AS t2 WHERE t2.AC_ID = t.AC_ID). Any thoughts?

Comment: @Zenon . . . There is not any function in that query, so the error message is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   mytable AS t
WHERE  t.capital = (SELECT MAX(capital)
                    FROM   mytable t2
                    WHERE  t2.id = t.id)
```

Incidentally, what do you want to do when there are two people with the same id and capital?

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte
(
select *, row_Number() over(Partition by ID order by Name ) as RowNumber
)

select * from cte
where RowNumber=1
```

try this, let me know ur comments on this.

Comment: Access SQL does not support CTEs or `OVER (PARTITION BY ...)`. (Access does not use T-SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct ID ,Name ,Surname,Capital from mytable order by ID
```

Comment: Based on the OP table, this will not work because there are two distinct ID=1 records based on ID, name, surname, and capital.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(Capital)
```

Answer (score 0):

select *,row_number() over(order by ID) as RNO into #temp1

select * from #temp as t where RNO not in (select max(RNO) from #temp as tt group by ID )

i think it will help you

Comment: That won't work in Access. Access does not use T-SQL.